# Function always return false, even the buffer is true value?

Tags: java, list, boolean

Why the function always return false even the buffer is true,
here is the code:

```
public class getCredentials {
    User login = new User();

    public boolean akses(String id, String password){
        boolean buffer=false;
        for (int i=0;i<login.sizeArrayList();i++){
            buffer = login.getId(i).equals(id) && login.getPassword(i).equals(password);
        }
        return buffer;
    }
}
```

Comment: are you sure this sizeArrayList is not empty????....

Comment: Post your [mcve].

Comment: This is a good opportunity to start using a debugger.  With a debugger you can step through the code line by line as it executes, observing the runtime behaviors and changing values of your variables.  When you do this, what specifically happens?  Does the loop iterate at all?  What is `buffer` set to in each iteration of the loop?  More specifically, what is it set to in the *last* iteration of the loop, since that's the value you return?

Comment: Are you meaning to return once a single match is found?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have an issue with the logic of the akses method,

that method can return **false** if the list is empty, because is returning the value of the initialization,

but also will return **true** if and only if, the id and password are correct for the last user in the list...

you dont need to iterate the whole list to validate an user actually.\

hpw to fix it

using java 8 you can stream the list, then filter using the credentials, then

1. check that the list is not empty
2. find any and if not found return null

---

example:

```
  public boolean access(String id, String password){
      User x = login.getArrayList().stream()
          .filter(p -> login.validateId(id) &&    
          login.validatePassword(password))
          .findAny().orElse(null);
        return x != null;
    }
```

Comment: should be a validation to id and password... i was the int for the last loop, for the sake of code is assuming there is a method that validates id and passw

Answer (score 0):

You can update the `akses` method like that :

```
public boolean akses(String id, String password){
   boolean buffer=false;
   for (int i=0;i<login.sizeArrayList() && !buffer;i++){
      buffer = login.getId(i).equals(id) && login.getPassword(i).equals(password);
   }
   return buffer;
}
```

(add `!buffer` in your loop condition)

Comment: Having non-standard end criteria in your for loop is just bad style which makes the code harder to read and understand.

Comment: Thanks for your comment ! I don't know it wasn't standard.

Comment: Just to be clear, there is no "official" standard on what to do in a for loop, but the usual two design patterns are "count from 0 to i" and "for(iterator.begin(); iterator.next();)" or similar, and if you stick anything more complex than that into your loop header, it is very liable to be overlooked by other coders. Thus, it is better to avoid it and put additional exit criteria into the loop's body itself, which makes the code clearer.

Answer (score 0):

As a previous answer has said: Assuming you have three users, and the second one is the one you are searching for.

The initialization before the loop will set "buffer" to false.
The first iteration of the loop will set "buffer" to false.
The second iteration will set "buffer" to true.
The third iteration will set "buffer" to false.

Then, the current value of "buffer" (which is "false") will be returned.

A correct bit of code would look like this:

```
public class getCredentials {
    User login = new User();

    public boolean akses(String id, String password){
        for (int i=0;i<login.sizeArrayList();i++){
            if(login.getId(i).equals(id) && login.getPassword(i).equals(password)) return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

An even better implementation would use a hash map or a database (with an index over the username column).

Answer (score 0):

The method returns the test of the last entry of the list. Is this intentional? I assume not. Maybe you like to write something like

```
buffer |=
```

If this is what you want, it is sufficient to return true immediately upon the first match.